# Calculating the timezone offset of a future date knowing only the current offset

Tags: timezone-offset

So 3rd March 2021 in US Eastern timezone it is 5 hours from UTC, and the offset is 300 minutes.

For a future date, 01-Apr-2021 the clocks will change and the offset will be different.

But if the code only knows the offset and doesnt know which timezone the original offset came from, am I correct that it would be impossible to determine the future dates timezone offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  There are many other time zones that also use the UTC-5 offset.  Some of them do not switch for DST at all.  Some of them switch for DST at a later or earlier date.  Some of them, UTC-5 *is* the DST offset and thus they switch *back* to UTC-6 instead of to UTC-4.

To have any understanding of how an offset will change over time, you need to identify the time zone, not just the offset.  Preferably, you would use an IANA time zone identifiers, such as `"America/New_York"`.

See [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), in particular the section titled "Time Zone != Offset".

Additionally, note that even with a time zone identified, future offsets are always just an estimate.  If a government changes their mind about what the time zone or DST rules are between the date your time zone data was last updated and the date such a change goes into effect, then the offset you determined might be incorrect under the new rules.  There's not much you can do about that, other than to not speculate too far into the future, and to urge governments not to make short-notice changes.